# How to chek in a eventbrite ticket with a barcode scanner pistol

Tags: barcode, qr-code, desktop, eventbrite, ticket-system

**Eventbrite events**

I created a event in eventbrite, now i want to do the check in of the tickets, i know i can do this my the app using my phone camera, but this works with qr codes.

My problem is that i want to make the check in with the barcode, i already buy a scanner pistols but i dont know how to make the check in with them to reflect on my eventbrite database.

So is there a way to make the check in of the tickets with the bar code scanner pistol.

Comment: No, barcode and QR code are different technologies and uses different protocols to work.

Comment: yeah but the tickets have the two types, barcodes and qr codes my question is how to scan the barcodes, the mobile app only scan qr codes.